# Find the functional dependencies that hold in a relation

Tags: database-design, normalization, dependencies

There is a question in my book that asks the following:

Suppose we have relation R ( A ,B ,C ,D ,E ) , with some set of FD’s, and we wish to project those FD’s onto relation S(A, B, C). Give the
    FD’s that hold in S if the FD’s for R are:

```
A->D
BD->E
AC->E
DE->B
```

**In each case, it is sufficient to give a minimal basis for the full set of FD’s of S.**

So I attempted to compute the closure of attributes for all of the subsets of (A,B,C).  I could not find any minimal basis of FD's for S.  I computer the closure of A, B, C, and AC, but I could not get all of the attributes.  A only implies AD, B only implies B, C only implies C and AC only implies ACE.  I could not find a functional dependency where there is a attribute on the left hand side that implies all of the attributes on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, define the (implied) numbering of your question:

1. A->D
2. BD->E
3. AC->E
4. DE->B

Then substituting 1 and 3 into 4 gives
(A)(AC) -> B
which reduces to just
 5. AC -> B.

Comment: Hi @Peter Geerkens thanks for the response.  So are you saying to compute the close of {AC}?  Would this give the minimal basis for the Functional Dependency of S?

Comment: I have tried to find the close of {AC} and got ACBE.  I still wasn't able to get all of the attributes to find the minimal basis.